# Parse, how to retrieve an object of type ParseGeoPoint

Tags: android, parse-platform, geopoints

I have a `JSONObject` that contains a `ParseGeoPoint`,I am trying this line of code to retrieve the `ParseGeoPoint` but with no luck

```
ParseGeoPoint storeAddress = (ParseGeoPoint) shopInfo.get("coordinates");
```

I made sure that shopInfo does has the geoPoint by checking its content

```
"coordinates":"ParseGeoPoint[30.132636,31.312510]"
```

The error I am getting is:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseGeoPoint
```

I tried `getParseGeoPoint("String");` but it is not recognizable as a key word, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clear. When you execute the line shopInfo.get("coordinates"), it returns just string representation of coordinates. You try to cast String object to ParseGeoPoint object which cannot work. To make it work, you need to divide the ParseGeoPoint[30.132636,31.312510] representation into latitude and longitude keys and values json pairs. Following that below line of code will work.

```
    JSONObject coordinates = shopInfo.getJSONObject("coordinates");
    double latitude= coordinates.getDouble("latitude");
    double longitude= coordinates.getDouble("longitude");   
    storeAddress =new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
```

Hope this helps. Regards.